How do I set the default browser used by classic snaps?
I'm using an application (Obsidian) which is packaged as a classic snap.  These, it seems, do not respect the user's default browser setting - apparently they run with $HOME set to something weird.  Is there a way to set the default browser for this application?
I have set the default browser through Settings -> Apps -> Default Apps.  When I open a terminal and run xdg-open http://google.com/ I get Chrome opening the Google home page.
But when I click on a link from Obsidian, it opens in Firefox.  How do I change that?
Edit:  And making /usr/bin/firefox a symlink to /usr/bin/google-chrome doesn't help.
